# Path do cookie não funciona

Tags: javascript, cookies

Crio um cookie com javascript, até ai beleza, mas quando utilizo o path ele simplesmente para de funcionar, assim funciona:

```
document.cookie="gravado=sim";
```

o problema é que desse jeito eu não consigo acessa-ló por outras paginas, ele só fica existente na página em questão, então tentei fazer isso:

```
document.cookie="gravado=sim; path=/";
```

mas desse jeito ele simplesmente para de funcionar, nem mesmo na página onde ele é criado ele funciona

Comment: E desse jeito mesmo! Testei aqui seu exemplo e deu certo

Comment: Não sei porque esta dando errado comigo, já tentei no chrome, firefox, opera, e nenhum deles funcionou, só funciona sem o path

Comment: ta mostrando nenhum erro no console não?

Comment: Aqui tb funcionou normal. Qual ambiente vc está usando: máquina local sem servidor, máquina local com servidor ou servidor remoto?